# How to apply the Themes for windows aplications in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, themes

I have a **winforms** in which I want apply a Theme. Is it possible? If possible please help me...how do I apply the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247256.aspx),

To create a page theme,

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the Web site for which you want to create a page theme, and then click Add ASP.NET Folder.
2. Click Theme.
   If the App_Themes folder does not already exist, Visual Web Developer creates it. Visual Web Developer then creates a new folder for the theme as a child folder of the App_Themes folder.
3. Type a name for the new folder.
   The name of this folder is also the name of the page theme. For example, if you create a folder named \App_Themes\FirstTheme, the name of your theme is FirstTheme.
4. Add files to your new folder for control skins, style sheets, and images that make up the theme.

[A Quick Tour of Themes in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163711.aspx)

Comment: Hi thank you for giving good response i will try these themes i hope this might be help to me...